# Bind array of strings in the butterknife

Tags: java, android, arrays, annotations, butterknife

I'm trying to bind array of strings using [`butterknife`](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). But seems that there is no way (but in [processor](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/src/main/java/butterknife/internal/ButterKnifeProcessor.java) there is a method to bind array).

Here is my code:

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="test_strings">
    <item>VK</item>
    <item>Facebook</item>
    <item>Twitter</item>
    <item>Instagram</item>
    <item>Google plus</item>
    <item>Google mail</item>
</string-array>
```

MainActivity

```
@Bind(R.string.test_strings)
protected String [] mStrings;
```

Comment: i never use it but ... https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/src/main/java/butterknife/internal/ButterKnifeProcessor.java#L163 ... @BindArray ?

Comment: @Selvin i've found the answer, heh here in the class : https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/src/main/java/butterknife/BindArray.java#L15

problem was I typed R.string.test_strings, when I should to type R.array.test_strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Five mins ago Butterknife 8.0.0 was [**released**](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/724652294269222912).

`R.string.test_array` change to `R.array.test_array`

And `@Bind` to `@BindArray`

Comment: FYI `@BindArray` is not released as of the time of this writing (v7.0.1)

Comment: @JakeWharton I noticed that, but seems, that it will work this way, right?

Comment: Yep! Just waiting on a few things before releasing.

Comment: @JakeWharton thanks for your work from all junior android devs. :)